# How does the team get home at the end of Stargate Atlantis' season one episode "Childhood's End"?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

At the end of Stargate: Atlantis' season one episode *Childhood's End*

> McKay reactivates the EM shield to continue protecting the villages from the threat of the Wraith.

Given that the puddle-jumper is deactivated by the device, how

> are they going to fly it back to the stargate if the shield is now activated once again? You can even hear the puddle-jumper powering up at the end of the episode.

I don't know if the answer would involve speculation, since the answer was not apparent to me during the episode, but I would be interested in either fact or speculation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It has been years since I've seen Stargate Atlantis, but I looked at a transcript of the episode here: [gateworld.net](http://www.gateworld.net/atlantis/s1/transcripts/106.shtml)

The episode makes it clear that the device does not protect the entire planet, but only the area around the village. (The ZPM does not have enough power) When McKay returns to the planet, he says:

> I've parked the Jumper outside the E.M. field, so we should be able to leave as soon as I finish.

That means all the scenes at the puddle jumper take place outside the field.

Comment: You took the words right off of my keyboard... Gosh, I miss SGA

Comment: I missed that bit of dialogue! The writers of this show don't seem to miss a beat when it comes to technicalities and scientific quandaries. However, it is interesting to note that after parking the jumper, McKay increases the field generator's strength by 50%. Perhaps he had already devised a method to increase the field strength and had parked the jumper well outside the area he had planned to cover.

Comment: @OranD.Lord Increasing the strength of the field does not necessarily mean that he increased the size of the field. He could have left the area it covered the same while just increasing the power of the field itself.

Comment: @Keeleon McKay: "I've been able to boost the coverage by over fifty percent without too much of a power increase so, uh, should be enough for a sizeable population growth." (from the transcript)

Comment: @Dennis_E Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Dennis_E It's definitely the area it covers, since the main purpose of "the sacrifice" is to keep the population from spreading out too far over the planet's surface. Either way, there's dialogue and reasonable, logical explanations for everything that could've happened, instead of just hand-waving.